# eye icon on password field sometimes is visible , sometimes not appearing visible

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code password of login form ( I am using bootstrap 4)

```
<div class="form-account-label-input">
   <label> Password <span class="star-red">&nbsp;*</span></label>
   <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" class="w-100">                                 
</div>
```

when I start to insert the password an icon eye appears like below

[image]

I haven't set any eye icon on my code. from where is it calling from? the problem is that this eye icon sometimes appear and sometimes doesn't. so I wanted to know where is it coming from disable and set an eye icon by myself on code?

### Update

I found that I have it just on Edge browser not in chrome

Comment: Based on your code snippet above, there is no code that calls the 'eye' icon for your password field. That might be extension of your browser like "password manager" OR some JavaScript code running to show that eye that you missed.

Comment: @detautama: so how can I disable to show my own eye icon?

Comment: You can inspect it in devtools and see the code where is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

CSS:

```
  /* password toggle start */
      .password-section {
         position: relative;
         display: inline-block;
      }

      .password-section .fa-eye {
         position: absolute;
         top: 76%;
         right: 22px; /* Adjust this value to control the icon's position */
         transform: translateY(-50%);
         cursor: pointer;
      }
      .password-section .fa-eye-slash {
         position: absolute;
         top: 76%;
         right: 22px; /* Adjust this value to control the icon's position */
         transform: translateY(-50%);
         cursor: pointer;
      }

   /* password toggle end */
```

Html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 password-section">
      
  <input class="form-control input-lg" id="password-field" name="password" type="Password">
  <span class="fa fa-eye " id="togglePassword"  ></span>

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  
     //  Toggle  Password Start
     $("#togglePassword").removeClass("fa fa-eye").addClass("fa fa-eye-slash");
     $("#togglePassword").click(function() {
        const passwordInput = $("#password-field");
        const type = passwordInput.attr("type");

        if (type === "password") {
            passwordInput.attr("type", "text");
            $("#togglePassword").removeClass("fa fa-eye-slash").addClass("fa fa-eye");
        } else {
            passwordInput.attr("type", "password");
            $("#togglePassword").removeClass("fa fa-eye").addClass("fa fa-eye-slash");
        }
    });
    //  Toggle  Password End
    
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this css works perfect for me

```
    input::-ms-reveal,
    input::-ms-clear {
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
**Try this**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap- 
  icons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384
ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
form i {
  margin-left: -30px;
  <h1>Sign In</h1>
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form>
        <p>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password"
                name="password" id="password" />
            <i class="bi bi-eye-slash"
                id="togglePassword"></i>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    const togglePassword = document
        .querySelector('#togglePassword');

    const password = document.querySelector('#password');

    togglePassword.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // Toggle the type attribute using
        // getAttribure() method
        const type = password
            .getAttribute('type') === 'password' ?
            'text' : 'password';
            
        password.setAttribute('type', type);

        // Toggle the eye and bi-eye icon
        this.classList.toggle('bi-eye');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
```

```css
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container{
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input id="password-field" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="Password123">
              <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).